# onsubmit not calling js function in chrome but submitting form directly

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome

My form is working fine in Firefox and IE. On calling onsubmit it calls js function and validates the code, and if validation is good, then it submits the form.

However, in chrome it is not doing validation, but simply submitting the form directly.

I am not sure why it is so, Did lot of search but in vain.

Any help will be great towards solving this issue.

Form Code:

```
<form name="myform" action="queryfeedback.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm(myform);">
<label for="labelField_Name" id="idLabel_Name"></label>
<input type="text" name="nameField_Name" id="idField_Name" placeholder="Enter your name here"/>
<br />
<label for="labelField_EMail" id="idLabel_EMail"></label>
<input name="nameField_EMail" type="text" id="idField_EMail" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail address here" />
<br />
<label for="labelField_Message" id="idLabel_Message"></label>
<textarea name="nameField_Message" id="idField_Message" placeholder="Enter your message for us here"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="Submit" name="nameSubmit" id="idButton_Submit" value="Submit"  alt="Submit Button"/>
</form>
```

Validation Code:

```
    function validateForm(form)
{ 
alert(form.nameField_Name.value);
//alert(formValueEMail.value);
//alert(formValueMessage.value);
if(form.nameField_Name.value=='')
{
    alert("Name field is required. Please fill it in.");
    form.nameField_Name.focus();
    form.nameField_Name.select();
    return false;
}
if(form.nameField_Name.value=='Enter your name here')
{
    alert("Name field is required. Please fill it in.");
    form.nameField_Name.focus();
    form.nameField_Name.select();
    return false;
}
if(form.nameField_EMail.value=='')
{
    alert("E-Mail Address field is required. Please fill it in.");
    form.nameField_EMail.focus();
    form.nameField_EMail.select();
    return false;
}
if(form.nameField_EMail.value=='Enter your E-Mail address here')
{
    alert("E-Mail Address field is required. Please fill it in.");
    form.nameField_EMail.focus();
    form.nameField_EMail.select();
    return false;
}
//Checking for correct format of EMail address.
var x=document.forms["myform"]["nameField_EMail"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
{
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
}
if(form.nameField_Message.value=='')
{
    alert("Message field is required. Please fill it in.");
    form.nameField_Message.focus();
    form.nameField_Message.select();
    return false;
}
if(form.nameField_Message.value=='Enter your message for us here')
{
    alert("Message field is required. Please fill it in.");
    form.nameField_Message.focus();
    form.nameField_Message.select();
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: Possibly your `validateForm` function is dying without completing in Chrome for some reason (e.g. it stops due to an error), so it never returns `false` to stop the submission.  Put an `alert` just before the finall return in `validateForm` to see if the program flow reached the bottom of the function on valid input.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the event parameter and running `event.preventDefault()` so it stops submitting the form until it is validated.

Comment: To see whether in Chrome my function is even called or not, I put an alert as the first line inside the function to see whether my function is even called or not. This alert is never shown, so it means function is not even called when submit button is pressed in chrome. This is strange as I do not know how to debug when my function is not even called as alert is not raised which is the first line in my function.

Comment: For some strange reason, my Chrome is not supporting. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

1. You aren't closing your function 'validateForm' with `}`. Therefore it could be throwing an error.
2. Use `onsubmit="return validateForm(this);"` Note that attribute name is `onsubmit` with no camel case and argument is `this`
3. `validateForm` should be a global function.

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qrZ8a/3/

Comment: Di the steps you suggested, made function global, used "this" as an argument and during my post curly bracket was missed at the end. So it was there originally in my code. But still Chrome is submitting the form directly without doing any validation. Not sure if there could be a bug in chrome itself for this.

Comment: I have given you a working example. If it still doesn't work for you. I am sorry.